# Instagram sidecar media type?

Tags: instagram, screen-scraping

What is an instagram sidecar media type? (Defined as GraphSidecar)
Resulting from this script: https://medium.com/swlh/tutorial-web-scraping-instagrams-most-precious-resource-corgis-235bf0389b0c

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Those are the Stories, as opposed to the plain GraphImage

Comment: This is incorrect. Michal Moravik's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

Not stories, it is sidecar.

GraphSidecar has a functionality of carousel, a collection of multiple permanent photos / videos. It appears in your instagram layout (your account), the same place as your photos and videos.

https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/22/instagram-carousels/